# How to fix SQL error 1064?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I've a problem, when I import the *sql* file after editing, it throws this error:

```
ErrorStatic analysis:2 errors were found during analysis.Unexpected
character. (near "" at position 0)Unexpected beginning of statement. 
(near "" at position 0)SQL query: SET SQL_MODE =
"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
```

*MySQL* said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near ' SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"' at line 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
SET @SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
select @SQL_MODE;
```

Comment: but appear to me another error .... its #1050   .                           CREATE TABLE `wp_cf_form_entries` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `form_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

MySQL said: Documentation
#1050 - Table 'wp_cf_form_entries' already exists

Comment: It says, you have already created that table name and you cannot do it to create again.